# On index change not working drop down list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to add on the selected index change method in My ASP.NET project. It was working perfectly before but suddenly my all drop-down list which I used in the project is not getting postback. And On selected Index change does not work now.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="selectDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control" Width="100%"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true">
                 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

```
log4net.ILog log  = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ClassNAME))
    protected void selectDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log.Info("select change in department ");
            ShowData();
        }
```

and my web.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="FinalConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\UAS_MSU\UAS_MSU\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" enableEventValidation="false" >
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            </namespaces>
            <controls>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
                <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.12.0" newVersion="2.0.12.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <log4net>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
        </root>
        <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="C:\\logs\\log.log" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I was try made some change in web.config but it was not worked...
change which I did `<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" enableEventValidation="false" >` to `<pages >`

Comment: "It was working perfectly before but suddenly..." Something changed in the code or configuration. What changed?

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that this is the result of some web config change.

Can you create a new test web page? Drag + drop in a dropdown list.

Say use this markup:

Now in the designer - display the property sheet.

[image]

Now, in the property sheet - select events, and double click on this:

[image]

Now, just put in say:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Debug.Print(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);    // get value of selected item (text)
Debug.Print(DropDownList1.Text);             // same as value
Debug.Print(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);    // get index (row) of selected item
}
```

Now of course you just type in the debug.print parts - the code stub should be generated correctly for you.

In fact, display the property sheet for YOUR existing dropdown, and double click on the selectedIndexChanged event on that property sheet. It sounds like the event code stub has become un-hooked or un-attached to the given control.

So, does a test web page work? Try that first.

If the test page works, then go back to your existing - try rebuilding the event code sub as per above.